Octave - Simulating a 3D Animation with static and dynamic parts
I want to create a 3D animation with static parts (not changing over time) in it. With dynamic parts, which should be added over time and with parts, which should be shown just on one single step. I thought it would be nice to create the static figure first, save it and just load it on each time step, so that it don't need to be redrawn each step (I thought that might be faster).
I'm not very familiare with the figure-model in octave - so maybe it's an easy way to the solution.
My idea was to do it like that:
%% initialize figure
  sim = figure(1);
  hold on
  axis equal

%% plot the static parts in the figure
...

%% save the static parts in a figure

  hgsave(sim,'Sim.ofig');

for 1:allTimeSteps

    %% plot dynamic parts, that should be shown over the whole simulation/on each time step
    ...
    
    %% save figure with additional dynamic parts
    hgsave(sim,'Sim.ofig');


    %% Reset figure 
    clf(sim);
    sim = openfig('Sim.ofig','reuse','visible');
    hold on

    %% add parts that should just be shown for a single time step

    ...

endfor

but it doens't work - it plots the static part in a single figure and clears it afterward. Then it shows the static part in a new figure and and switches to the parts, that should just be shown on each step - without the static parts anymore. The dynamic parts which should be shown over the whole simulation arn't added to the figure (just the parts of the single step).
I also tried without the clf in it - but then I just get all at once in one figure (also the parts, that just be shown on one single step).
I don't get it - how can I get the desired behaviour?
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
Solved it otherwise - now without saving and loading everything again. I just recreated the whole figure every step. To be honestly: it makes much more sense, because it's also faster to recreate it in RAM than trying to write and read everything from and to disc.
